# Sequel gem: Why does eager().all work but eager().first doesn't?

Tags: ruby, associations, eager-loading, sequel

I'm storing a user's profile fields in a separate table, and want to look up a user by email address (for password reset). Trying to determine the best approach, and ran into this unexpected behaviour inconsistency.

### Schema

```
create_table(:users) do
  String        :username,                  primary_key: true
  ...
end

create_table(:user_fields) do
  primary_key   :id
  foreign_key   :user_id, :users, type: String, null: false
  String        :label, null: false
  String        :value, null: false
end
```

### Console Session

This version works (look up field, eager load it's associated user, call .all, take the first one):

```
irb(main):005:0> a = UserField.where(label: 'email', value: 'testuser@test.com').eager(:user).all[0]
I, [2015-09-29T17:54:06.273263 #147]  INFO -- : (0.000176s) SELECT * FROM `user_fields` WHERE ((`label` = 'email') AND (`value` = 'testuser@test.com'))
I, [2015-09-29T17:54:06.273555 #147]  INFO -- : (0.000109s) SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`username` IN ('testuser'))
=> #<UserField @values={:id=>2, :user_id=>"testuser", :label=>"email", :value=>"testuser@test.com"}>
irb(main):006:0> a.user
=> #<User @values={:username=>"testuser"}>
```

You can see both queries (field and user) are kicked off together, and when you try to access a.user, the data's already loaded.

But when I try calling .first in place of .all:

```
irb(main):007:0> b = UserField.where(label: 'email', value: 'testuser@test.com').eager(:user).first
I, [2015-09-29T17:54:25.832064 #147]  INFO -- : (0.000197s) SELECT * FROM `user_fields` WHERE ((`label` = 'email') AND (`value` = 'testuser@test.com')) LIMIT 1
=> #<UserField @values={:id=>2, :user_id=>"testuser", :label=>"email", :value=>"testuser@test.com"}>
irb(main):008:0> b.user
I, [2015-09-29T17:54:27.887718 #147]  INFO -- : (0.000172s) SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`username` = 'testuser') LIMIT 1
=> #<User @values={:username=>"testuser"}>
```

The eager load fails -- it doesn't kick off the second query for the user object until you try to reference it with b.user.

What am I failing to understand about the sequel gem API here? And what's the best way to load a model instance based on the attributes of it's associated models?  (find user by email address)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eager loading only makes sense when loading multiple objects.  And in order to eager load, you need all of the current objects first, in order to get all associated objects in one query.  With `each`, you don't have access to all current objects first, since you are iterating over them.

You can use the `eager_each` plugin if you want Sequel to handle things internally for you, though note that it makes `dataset.first` do something similar to `dataset.all.first` for eagerly loaded datasets.  But it's better to not eager load if you only need one object, and to call `all` if you need to eagerly load multiple ones.

Comment: In other words, eager() is a tool to solve the 1+N query problem, which doesn't apply to this case, and I should just be happy with loading the UserField instance, then loading the User reference in a second query -- which I agree with.